# Converting latitude and longitude to UTM coordinates in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, utm, pyproj

I have dataframe contain longitude and latitude coordinates for each point. I want to convert the geographical coordinates for each point to UTM coordinates.

I tried to use utm module (https://pypi.org/project/utm/)

```
import utm
df=df.withColumn('UTM',utm.from_latlon(fn.col('lat'),fn.col('lon')))
```

but I obtain this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-8b21f98738ca> in <module>()
----> 1 df=df.withColumn('UTM',utm.from_latlon(fn.col('lat'),fn.col('lon')))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\utm\conversion.py in from_latlon(latitude, longitude, force_zone_number)
    152        .. _[1]: http://www.jaworski.ca/utmzones.htm
    153     """
--> 154     if not -80.0 <= latitude <= 84.0:
    155         raise OutOfRangeError('latitude out of range (must be between 80 deg S and 84 deg N)')
    156     if not -180.0 <= longitude <= 180.0:

F:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\column.py in __nonzero__(self)
    633 
    634     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 635         raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
    636                          "'~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.")
    637     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

***update:***

After creating udf that applying utm or pyproj function

The result is:

```
+--------------------+
|                 UTM|
+--------------------+
|[Ljava.lang.Objec...|
|[Ljava.lang.Objec...|
|[Ljava.lang.Objec...|
|[Ljava.lang.Objec...|
|[Ljava.lang.Objec...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: You need to create a udf and apply the `utm` function.

Comment: ok. thank you for your reply

Comment: If you found the answer useful, do upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import utm
from pyspark.sql.types import *

utm_udf_x = F.udf(lambda x,y: utm.from_latlon(x,y)[0], FloatType())
utm_udf_y = F.udf(lambda x,y: utm.from_latlon(x,y)[1], FloatType())

df = df.withColumn('UTM_x',utm_udf_x(F.col('lat'), F.col('lon')))
df = df.withColumn('UTM_y',utm_udf_y(F.col('lat'), F.col('lon')))
```

Although I am not sure why did you write `[1]` at the end.

Comment: I follow the above lines but I obtained error : TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: 'Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o513.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 20.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 20.0 (TID 40, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):'

Comment: @ mayank agrawal ! you help me for solving this new  issue?

Comment: the result is not clear can you check the update part

Comment: what exactly should be the output type of `utm` ?

Comment: the result of function is a tuple, there is any way to extract the x_coordinate in new column and the y_coordinate in another new column inside the udf function

Comment: utm.from_latlon(51.2, 7.5)
>>> (395201.3103811303, 5673135.241182375, 32, 'U')