# Unable to convert utm to latlong using pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and  am stuck with the following problem:

What I am trying to do: 
I need to convert co-ordinates that are in UTM zone-10 to latitude and Longitude. I am trying do this on a dataframe and have done the below to achieve that. The below code was created referring to another post
[Converting latitude and longitude to UTM coordinates in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076977/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-utm-coordinates-in-pyspark)

```
import utm

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions, types, udf

from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType, DoubleType, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('reddit average df').getOrCreate()


a = spark.createDataFrame([{"X": 488769.792012, "Y": 5457280.44999}])

a.show()
```

---

```
|            X|            Y|

+-------------+-------------+

|488769.792012|5457280.44999|

+-------------+-------------+
```

---

```
utm_udf_x = functions.udf(lambda x, y: utm.to_latlon(x, y, 10, 'U')[0], DoubleType())

c = a.withColumn('Latitude', utm_udf_x(functions.col('X'), functions.col('Y')))

c.show()
```

However while doing so I am facing with the below problem(first few line of error pasted here):

```
19/11/13 11:15:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 7)
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$evaluate$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$evaluate$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:89)
```

I have tried with changing the data type presuming that could be the problem. But I could infer the types are same. Appreciate if anyone could help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

utm.to_latlon returns an numpy object which can't be casted to pysparks DoubleType implicitly:

```py
type(utm.to_latlon(488769.792012 , 5457280.44999, 10, 'U')[0])
#Output
#numpy.float64
```

Just call `.item()` to get a ordinary python float object which can be converted to pysparks DoubleType:

```py
utm_udf_x = functions.udf(lambda x, y: utm.to_latlon(x, y, 10, 'U')[0].item(), DoubleType())
```